# google chart update mysql query from form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

I am trying to update a [google gnatt chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart) with html date pickers and refresh the page to show the new choosen data. However, I have not been able to make them work which is a major bummer. The closest I came was from another link on [Stack**overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781012/form-submission-using-php-mysql-date-query-to-a-google-visualization-page) and its influence is present in my code but it didn't help. My chart works fine left alone but I would like the ability to sort by dates to narrow down data and eventually do more filtering using the same basic methods that elude me now. Currently, I am able to use GET to publish the dates to the main page url and pick them out using javascript but I can't pass them to the php page, getTrackerdata.php, through ajax.  If I do run the page as I have below I get the chart as normal unfiltered.

with the console log I see that the date was picked from the url as it prints

```
startdate: 2016-02-05 enddate: 2016-03-25
```

If I just run the php page with the url as follows

```
getTrackerdata.php?startdate=2016-02-13&enddate=2016-03-25
```

It returns the appropriate data and is filtered within the correct dates

**Selections from my site**:

Script:

```
 $("#drawChart").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    drawChart();
 });

 function GetUrlValue(VarSearch){
     var SearchString = window.location.search.substring(1);
     var VariableArray = SearchString.split('&');
     for(var i = 0; i < VariableArray.length; i++){
         var KeyValuePair = VariableArray[i].split('=');
         if(KeyValuePair[0] == VarSearch){
             return KeyValuePair[1];
         }
     }
 }

 function testAjax() {
    var startdate  = GetUrlValue('startdate');
    var enddate  =   GetUrlValue('enddate');

    return $.ajax({
             url: "getTrackerdata.php",
             dataType: "text",
             data: ({"startdate": startdate, "enddate": enddate}),
             async: false
          }).responseText;
 }

     function drawChart() {



     var jsonData = testAjax();
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(JSON.parse(jsonData));
```

html:

```
<div id="hed">
  <h1><strong>CARF PROJECT TRACKER </strong></h1>
</div>
<div id="picker">
  <form action="ProjectTracker.html" method="GET">
   From: <input type="date" class="hasDatepicker" name="startdate"  id="datepicker"> To: <input type="date" name="enddate" class="hasDatepicker"    id="datepicker2">  <input type="submit" id="drawChart"  >
  </form>
</div>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
   <a href="ProjectTracker/home.php"> Link to Edit Chart</a>
 <div id="table_div"></div>
```

php:

```
$From = $_POST['startdate']; 
$Too = $_POST['enddate'];
if($From === NULL){
$result = ("SELECT `Project`, `Description`, `Notes`, `StartYear`, `EndYear`, `Duration` , `PercentComplete`, `Dependancy` FROM `Main`");
}else{
  $result = ("SELECT `Project`, `Description`, `Notes`, `StartYear`, `EndYear`, `Duration` , `PercentComplete`, `Dependancy` FROM `Main` WHERE `StartYear` BETWEEN '$From' and '$Too'");
}
```

Am I in the right direction? Is there a less messy way than using GET?

Thank you

edit: changed wording
edit 2: changed to latest example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the following.

```
function testAjax() {
var startdate  = GetUrlValue('startdate');
var enddate  =   GetUrlValue('enddate');

return $.ajax({
         url: "getTrackerdata.php",
         type: "POST", // This is needed to send data
         dataType: "text",
         data: ({'startdate': startdate, 'enddate': enddate}),
         async: false
      }).responseText;

}
```